# Is there a significant delay in looking up a multi-dimensional array's value(s) in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

Which of the following is the more optimal approach? Option A or B?

Option A: looking up the multi-dimensional array's value twice

```
if($my_array["dimension1"]["dimension2"]["dimension3"] > 0 ) {
    echo $my_array["dimension1"]["dimension2"]["dimension3"];
}
```

Option B: looking up the multi-dimensional array's value once, but with an extra variable defintion

```
$dimension3 = $my_array["dimension1"]["dimension2"]["dimension3"];
if($dimension3 > 0) {
    echo $dimension3;
}
```

Personally I find option B more readable, but this code is being executed a couple hundred thousand times, so the more optimal approach would take preference.

Comment: Unless you've identified as the bottleneck in your code, go with the most readable. You can identify whether it is a bottleneck using a profiler or by timing sections of code with microtime()

Comment: I would be very surprised if you could actually demonstrate a difference in a real-world scenario -- but if you are not convinced, why not measure it yourself?

Comment: Don't worry about micro optimizations like this :S

Answer (score 1):

I think option B is better with respect to performances.

At runtime it is necessary to find the memory position pointed by the cell of the multidimentsional array you specified. while entering a simple variable value is more quick.

So if you enter the array once and store the value in a temporary variable of course you script will allocate more memory (to store the temporary variable) but then you will'be very quick to enter the second times the value you need!

Of course other type of optimizations can happen so to prove what I said the better way is to test it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

As your projects get bigger (referring to the number of calling such arrays), you'd want to go with the option B... but that's so minor I couldn't think of an example with a really noticable difference.

Answer (score -1):

I would go for option A. Simply, because option B has an extra variable allocation, plus an extra assignment operation.

Minor gain, though; but still a gain. :-)